# AdMob Rewarded Video Ads Failed to Load inside Fragment in Android

Tags: android, admob

Admob rewarded video ads fail to load in fragment.
I think there is problem in these two lines

`mAd = MobileAds.getRewardedVideoAdInstance(getActivity());`
`mAd.setRewardedVideoAdListener(this);`

Please check the code below.
The code is working fine in Activity but doesn't work in Fragment.

```
public class FragmentWatchEarn extends Fragment implements RewardedVideoAdListener {
    int coins = 0;

    View rootView;
    Button bAdmob;
    TextView tvCoins;

    private RewardedVideoAd mAd;//Admob
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_watch_earn, container, false);
        bAdmob = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnAdmob);

        admobAdsPart();

        return rootView;
    }
    private void admobAdsPart() {
        mAd = MobileAds.getRewardedVideoAdInstance(getActivity()); //Might me Problem in this line
        mAd.setRewardedVideoAdListener(this); //Might me Problem in this line
        loadAd();

        bAdmob.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(mAd.isLoaded()){
                    mAd.show();
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Ad not yet loaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    loadAd();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void loadAd() {
        if (!mAd.isLoaded()) {
            mAd.loadAd("ca-app-pub-5059726881726792/4575431467", new AdRequest.Builder().build());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdLoaded() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdOpened() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoStarted() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdClosed() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRewarded(RewardItem rewardItem) {
        coins = coins + 20;
        myRef.setValue("" + coins);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad(int i) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Admob Ad Failed to load", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This code works for me.

With this code you dont have to implement the OnRewardListener in the top side of your XXXXXFragment.java

```
private RewardedVideoAd mRewardedVideoAd;

@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        mRewardedVideoAd = MobileAds.getRewardedVideoAdInstance(getContext());
        mRewardedVideoAd.setRewardedVideoAdListener(rewardedVideoAdListener);

        CircleImageView circleImageView = (CircleImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_play);
        circleImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                loadRewardedVideoAd();
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }

    RewardedVideoAdListener rewardedVideoAdListener = new RewardedVideoAdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRewardedVideoAdLoaded() {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "onRewardedVideoAdLoaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onRewardedVideoAdOpened() {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "onRewardedVideoAdOpened", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onRewardedVideoStarted() {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "onRewardedVideoStarted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onRewardedVideoAdClosed() {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "onRewardedVideoAdClosed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            ////// UpdateDataBase
        }

        @Override
        public void onRewarded(RewardItem reward) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getString(R.string.on_rewarded_video) + " " +  reward.getAmount() + " " + reward.getType(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // Reward the user.
        }

        @Override
        public void onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication() {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad(int i) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };

    private void loadRewardedVideoAd() {
        mRewardedVideoAd.loadAd("ca-app-pub-#################/##########",
                new AdRequest.Builder().build());
    }
```

I hope it can helps you

Answer (score 0):

Try to change:

```
mAd = MobileAds.getRewardedVideoAdInstance(getContext());
```

I have same code and it's working.