# How to use AdMob rewarded in fragment

Tags: android, admob, android-fragmentactivity, admob-rewardedvideoad

I am newbie in Android and I am trying to use AdMob rewarded ad in fragment.My app have bottom navigation bar which has three fragments. I want to know how to load rewarded ad in fragment.

Answer (score 0):

[documentation](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/rewarded)

In documentation *this* means context in activity, in fragment, you should use *requireActivity()*.  Always check the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference in the usage of Rewarded ads apart from the context and the code in onCreate of activity to the onCreateView() part of the lifecycle method .

Here is a reference code

[Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47397537/13533028)

```
private RewardedVideoAd mRewardedVideoAd;

@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        mRewardedVideoAd = MobileAds.getRewardedVideoAdInstance(getContext());
        mRewardedVideoAd.setRewardedVideoAdListener(rewardedVideoAdListener);

        CircleImageView circleImageView = (CircleImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_play);
        circleImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                loadRewardedVideoAd();
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }

    RewardedVideoAdListener rewardedVideoAdListener = new RewardedVideoAdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRewardedVideoAdLoaded() {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "onRewardedVideoAdLoaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onRewardedVideoAdOpened() {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "onRewardedVideoAdOpened", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onRewardedVideoStarted() {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "onRewardedVideoStarted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onRewardedVideoAdClosed() {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "onRewardedVideoAdClosed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            ////// UpdateDataBase
        }

        @Override
        public void onRewarded(RewardItem reward) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getString(R.string.on_rewarded_video) + " " +  reward.getAmount() + " " + reward.getType(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // Reward the user.
        }

        @Override
        public void onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication() {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad(int i) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };

    private void loadRewardedVideoAd() {
        mRewardedVideoAd.loadAd("ca-app-pub-#################/##########",
                new AdRequest.Builder().build());
    }
```